# Print last element of each row

Tags: awk

How can one print the element after the last tab in a file?

Exemple: File1

```
A    3    8    6    7
B    4    6    2    3    6    8
c    1    9
```

would return:

```
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can make smart use of the `NF` variable in `awk`

```
awk '{print $NF}' File1
```

From `man awk`

> **NF**          The number of fields in the current input record.

So `NF` will give you the amount of fields and `$NF` will then expand to `$3` for example, which you can use in a print statement.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the last field only and not both first and last, you could try:

```
rev file | cut -f 1
```

The `rev` reverses each line of the file and the `cut` prints only the first field (fields are defined by tabs by default). Since the line has been reversed, the first field is the original last field.

The above works in your given example but, as @Bernhard points out below, it will print fields that are longer than a single character reversed. In those cases, you will need a second rev:

```
 rev file | cut -f 1 | rev
```

Comment: If the last field is more than one character, it will be shown in reverse, so you'll need another pipe to `rev`.

Comment: @Bernhard d'oh! Of course it will, thanks. Didn't really think of it since I would also use awk for this. I just posted this answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed` for such operation:

```
sed 's/.* //' file # where ' ' -- is your delimiter
```

It will delete all symbols before the delimiter. If your file is tab-separated, use:

```
sed 's/.*\t//' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Bernhard's answer is the correct one. For fun and completeness, bash:

```
while read -a fields; do
    echo ${fields[-1]}
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is really the tool for the job here but for the sake of completeness here's a GNU `grep` way

```
grep -oE '[^[:space:]]+$' file
7
8
9
```